# Using trackbars to display and distort a cross section

Tags: c#, object

The question asked to calculate the volume of a swimming pool and display its cross section in a picture box.  Width of the pool is fixed at 5 meters and the length is fixed at 20 meters.
The program should have 2 trackbars - one to adjust the depth of the deep end and one to adjust the depth of the shallow end.  The minimum depth of each end is one meter, choose suitable maximum and minimum track bar values at design time.

Volume = averageDepth * width * length

The trackbar for the deep end of the pool adjusts the depth perfectly.
The trackbar for the shallow end changes the cross section and does not diplay one of the lines when used.

Could someone please help me correct this and figure it out?
Heres the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Graphics paper;
    private int averageDepth;
    private int answer;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        paper = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        deepEndTrackbar.Minimum = 120;
        deepEndTrackbar.Maximum = 180;
        deepEndLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(deepEndTrackbar.Value);
        shallowEndTrackbar.Minimum = 120;
        shallowEndTrackbar.Maximum = 180;
        shallowEndLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(shallowEndTrackbar.Value);

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics paper;
        paper = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 40, 50, 200, 50);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 40, 50, 40, 120);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 200, 50, 200, 90);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 200, 90, 40, 120);
    }

    private void deepEndTrackbar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        deepEndLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(deepEndTrackbar.Value);
        paper.Clear(Color.White);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 40, 50, 200, 50);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 200, 50, 200, 90);
       paper.DrawLine(pen, 40, 50, 40, deepEndTrackbar.Value);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 200, 90, 40, deepEndTrackbar.Value);
    }

    private void shallowEndTrackbar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        shallowEndLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(shallowEndTrackbar.Value);
        paper.Clear(Color.White);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 40, 50, 200, shallowEndTrackbar.Value);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 200, 50, 200, shallowEndTrackbar.Value);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deepEndTrackbar_Scroll routine seems to work. But it doesn't really as it does not use the value of the shallowEndTrackbar. In fact both routines should draw the very same lines:

```
    paper.DrawLine(pen, 40, 50, 200, 50);
    paper.DrawLine(pen, 200, 50, 200, shallowEndTrackbar.Value);
    paper.DrawLine(pen, 40, 50, 40, deepEndTrackbar.Value);
    paper.DrawLine(pen, 200, shallowEndTrackbar.Value, 40, deepEndTrackbar.Value);
```

This is the bare minimum correction.

The next step would be to have this code only once. The direct solution would be to call the same event for both Trackbars.

However all these things are only working on the surface. Minimize the window, restore and look: All Lines are gone! You need to persist the drawing!

The right place for the code is the Paint event of the PictureBox. You could override it, but it is simpler to just code it: Doubleclick it in the properties tab and insert the code.

Prefix this line to the code:

```
paper = e.Graphics;
```

And replace all drawing in the two TrackBar scroll events for this:

```
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```

Another error is with initializing the Trackbar. Judging from the initial display one value (90) is not in the allowed range (120-180).

You also don't need the lines

```
private Graphics paper;
```

and

```
paper = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
```

**Edit**: As requested here is a complete solution.

**Note**: I have added a LengthTrackbar and moved the drawing down by 100 pixels:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Pen pen = Pens.Black;

    //private int averageDepth;
    //private int answer;

    public Form1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        deepEndTrackbar.Minimum = 120;
        deepEndTrackbar.Maximum = 180;
        deepEndLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(deepEndTrackbar.Value);

        shallowEndTrackbar.Minimum = 120;
        shallowEndTrackbar.Maximum = 180;
        shallowEndLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(shallowEndTrackbar.Value);

        lengthTrackbar.Minimum = 120;
        lengthTrackbar.Maximum = 180;
        lengthLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(lengthTrackbar.Value);

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // reset the trackbar values:
        shallowEndTrackbar.Value = 120;
        deepEndTrackbar.Value = 120;
        lengthTrackbar.Value = 120;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void deepEndTrackbar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        deepEndLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(deepEndTrackbar.Value);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void shallowEndTrackbar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        shallowEndLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(shallowEndTrackbar.Value);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void lengthTrackbar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lengthLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(lengthTrackbar.Value);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }


    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics paper = e.Graphics;
        // reset the paper
        paper.Clear(Color.White);

        // draw the 2D front lines:
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 40, 150, 200, 150);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 200, 150, 200, 100 + shallowEndTrackbar.Value);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 40, 150, 40, 100 + deepEndTrackbar.Value);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 200, 100 + shallowEndTrackbar.Value, 40, 
                                 100 + deepEndTrackbar.Value);

        // perspective 2:3
        int lx = lengthTrackbar.Value / 2;
        int ly = lengthTrackbar.Value / 3;

        // draw the outer 3D lines:
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 40, 150, 40 + lx, 150 - ly);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 200, 150, 200 + lx, 150 - ly);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 200, 100 + shallowEndTrackbar.Value, 
                            200 + lx, 100 - ly + shallowEndTrackbar.Value);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 40 + lx, 150 - ly, 40 + lx + 200 - 40, 150 - ly);
        paper.DrawLine(pen, 200 + lx, 150 - ly, 
                            200 + lx,  100 -ly + shallowEndTrackbar.Value);


    }

}
```

Comment: thank you but im okay with the formula , i made the changes but it gave me a bad compilation error and i lost the data,please if its not too much trouble , could you show me how you exactly did it?